# perl: warning: Setting locale failed

Tags: ssh, osx, perl, locale

I bought a VPS, Centos 7.

However, I was able to understand what was going on with SSH and connected to my WHM.

After connecting, I get a list of errors and there is something like this:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = (unset)
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "C"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "C"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

My system is the latest MacOS Mojave.

**UPDATE**: Finally it worked :) It was enough in the terminal in my system to enter these two commands.

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

The server is from the US, so I think that's why I had to set the language.
The problem is now that if I turn off the terminal and turn it on again, I have to do the export command again. But it's already better than it was, I'm looking further ... :)

**UPDATE 2:**

I had to add these 2 lines, but to the file ~ / .bash_profile, now everything works even after the terminal is restarted.

Comment: are you executing a Perl script intentionally, or as a part of your login? It would help see that Perl script.

Comment: The locale-related environment variables seems to be set incorrectly.  You can remedy this by setting them correctly. Setting `LC_ALL` to the single character `C` or the string `POSIX` is a safe thing to do. You may also want to investigate your shell startup files to see if any `LC_*` variables are set in there, or at least set `LC_CTYPE` to `C` as well.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - These errors appear immediately when I connect to the server. The only thing I write in the command is ssh root @ myip.

Comment: @Kusalananda - I found that in the system it can be changed eg in the / etc / environment file. I gave there something like LANG = C and LC_ALL = C, unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: Thanks @Maciej your update in the question helped me fix the issue. (but we need to close terminal and try again to verify if its working . :)

Answer (score 0):

### Installing

On Fedora, RHEL, Redhat, CentOS I used

```
sudo dnf install langpacks-de
```

for the german (de) language packs. Logged out and in and it worked.

Search for other langpacks with

```
dnf search langpacks-
```

### Changing

To list available locales I used

```
localectl list-locales
```

And to set a new one

```
sudo localectl set-locale de_DE.utf8
```